# Export-SPWeb error list template not installed

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, export

I am getting below error I am trying to export from sharepoint 2010 foundation server.

Is there anyway I can ignore these kind of errors and export simply?

```
PS C:\> Export-SPWeb -Identity http://sp2010/dept  -Path c:\\temp\backUp.dat
Export-SPWeb : Feature '0be49fe9-9bc9-409d-abf9-702753bd878d' for list template
 '2100' is not installed in this farm.  The operation could not be completed.
At line:1 char:13
+ Export-SPWeb <<<<  -Identity http://sp2010/dept  -Path c:\\temp\backUp.dat
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...CmdletExportWeb:
   SPCmdletExportWeb) [Export-SPWeb], SPException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletExportWe
   b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-Force` parameter http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895(v=office.15).aspx

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity http://sp2010/dept  -Path c:\\temp\backUp.dat -Force
```

Alternatively you can do a backup using Central Admin http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/video/backup-and-restore-a-sharepoint-2010-site-collection.aspx

Comment: If I apply -force. Still getting same error.

Comment: Try central admin backup feature.

Comment: same this I got from central admin too "Feature '0be49fe9-9bc9-409d-abf9-702753bd878d' for list template '2100' is not installed in this farm. The operation could not be completed."

Comment: Is there any free tool available?

Answer (score 0):

The id `{0be49fe9-9bc9-409d-abf9-702753bd878d}` is the feature Id for `Slide Library`.
As per my knowledge the Slide Library feature is **not** present in SharePoint **Foundation** 2010. Its available only in SharePoint 2010 Server edition.

If you are using SharePoint 2010 Server edition. You should check if **SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection Features** is enabled or not. If this is Deactivated, just Activate it and try Exporting again.

Comment: I have moved from sharepoint 2007 (MOSS) to SharePoint 2010 Foundation. Now I am tryhing to export sites to Sharepoint 2013 Foundation.

Comment: The Slide Library were part of MOSS 2007 and SharePoint 2010 server. They are discontinued in SharePoint 2013(refer https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Discontinued-features-and-modified-functionality-in-Microsoft-SharePoint-2013-bbbb0815-2538-4f1d-b647-1f7f6d508c93?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). As a workaround i can suggest to backup the content of the slide library and then delete the library from the site. Now, you should be able to export the site.